# Opening android AOSP native applications in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I need to edit the original Android Apps from packages 
in terms make my own distro/mod.. 
I want to make changes to the In Call screen, lock screen, contacts, calendar etc.. 
I understand that for doing this I will have to build everything from 
source, 
however I need to edit the source and to do so I need to open the OS provided apps as 
eclipse projects,

When I did I saw that there are

1. missing imports which are hidden in the SDK (or missing)
2. hidden parameters within the classes..

I don't want to use reflection since the whole code is here and 
available, but how do you build a platform development kit..

or PDK ?:)

Can any one help?

Comment: If you don't have luck here try the IRC channels on freenode for #android-root and #cyanogenmod.  There may even be instructions on the cyanogenmod wiki

Comment: were you able to modify the stock apps in eclipse?  I'm trying to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start by reading [the documentation](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html).

---

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to download some single project from AOSP and compile it using the SDK, odds are very strong that it will not work, and that you will encounter problems like the ones you cite. You do not build Android by building individual apps; you build Android ("my own distro/mod") by building the entire firmware. Most AOSP applications are not designed to be compiled by the SDK, but need the whole firmware.

Comment: actually that was my error, I was trying to import separate projects and satisfy their dependencies... The thing I could not understand was that I need to open THE WHOLE SOURCE CODE as one big project. :)
Thanks for the slap in the face dude :)

Comment: Wonder how Google work, how for example do they modify the Contacts app? The AOSP is not an Android project.

Comment: @powder366: Instructions for building the entire OS, including AOSP apps like Contacts, can be found at http://source.android.com

Comment: I want to build Contacts as Android project. AOSP is a Java project. Im aware of http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html but I want to build Contacts as a Android project and that is what I asked, how do Google work?

Comment: @powder366: Mostly, Google follows the instructions at http://source.android.com. I am under the impression that, after an initial complete build, there are ways of building an individual app that does not require a complete OS rebuild. However, I do not know what that particular process is.

Comment: I build the AOSP successfully from Unix. Importing (the whole AOSP) it into Eclipse has errors (as a Java project). I found out that the .classpath in AOSP is not up-to-date. Then I thought how does really Google work, I mean when changing for example the Contacts app they must work with it as a Android project, but I have found no reference how they build this or use it? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Using eclipse to browse and edit AOSP](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html). You can atleast edit your code using eclipse, but you will have to use AOSP build system to build your distro.

You might also check [Debugging Android Java Framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html) as that would help debug your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Eclipse,
then go to "window" +"preferences" +"android"
there you will get sdk location,then give the appropriate path of the android sdk for proper run...