# Is it possible to force Eclipse to run, despite having errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source

Is it possible to change settings in Eclipse so that, despite having known errors, build and run is forced? (I.e. "Your project contains error(s)..." does not stop you from packaging an .APK)

I do realize this is likely terrible practice, but I am using this only to test out some idea on my own Android phone. For those who are interested, the long story leading up to this question is this:

*I want to run a custom version of the AOSP Settings app on my own phone. As I understand it, this can only be done by building the whole firmware because it makes use of components hidden to the sdk. I do not want to build the whole firmware, so my hair-brained idea was that if I forced it to run it would find those classes available once on the phone. (Full disclosure: I do not suspect this will actually work, but I want to prove my hypothesis wrong myself. Explanations of why not would be welcomed, but please do also consider the original question.)*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to right click on the file/folder-->Build Path-->Exclude. Here is SO discussion on this topic. [Exclude folders from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736208/how-to-exclude-a-folder-that-is-producing-warnings-errors-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think either of these solutions do exactly what I want. I actually do want to include the code which produces the error into my .APK build, I just don't want it to prevent the build from happening. Maybe what I am asking for is not possible?

Comment: Yes, what you are asking is not possible, what we suggested is workaround. Any special reason why you need to include the error code in APK, when it is not being compiled and used?

Comment: I am likely not understanding the compilation process for Android, but my thought was that these classes are missing when the code sits in Eclipse (because they are hidden to the SDK,) but, if I just get them onto a phone, those same classes I am referencing might then become callable, because they are not hidden in the actual Android source on the device. That was the theory I wanted to test.

Comment: Needless to say, I have a hobbyist's level of understanding of all this. Thanks for any info that can set me straight.

Comment: There is nothing like hidden to SDK, you will get hidden code as Jars which need to be in classpath of your project. Any code developed by you need to run on any phone/machine, it should be compiled to the OS running on that phone, Code which is not compiled is not going to run on any phone in Java/Android world.

Comment: Accepting this as answered with the answer: "It is not possible to force 'Run' in Eclipse, when there are errors in Android code."

Answer (score 0):

You won't be fine just excluding folders because what I guess is that you have errors scattered all over the project.
So my suggestion is to solve the problems one by one probably creating mock objects if the project is accessing hidden APIs.

Comment: You are correct. There are thousands of scattered errors. Unfortunately none can be solved because they are actually references to hidden/secured classes. He is doing something different, but it is explained well by this SO post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303812/opening-android-aosp-native-applications-in-eclipse). I was hoping to still be able to package the APK despite having unsolved errors. Is this even theoretically possible?